# How to implement Volume Control In AVplayer for a Video file?

Tags: ios, volume, avplayer, video-player

i am working on audio/video player i have implemented volume control for audio files using AVaudioPlayer. I want to have volume control for video file how should i do that if any one know the way to accomplish it please Point me the way to accomplish it .

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007550-CH1-SW9 refer this link use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Documentation: [AV Foundation Programming Guide - Playback](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1)

They are using AVPlayer class, it has volume property. You should look at it [AVPlayer class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)